# Unable to pass jmeter post call's dynamic response to get call

Tags: json, regex, post, jmeter, dynamic-variables

am new to JMeter. I hit the multiple "post" calls with the different data sets. Every post call results in unique id as the response. I want to again pass the each unique id to "get" call with 5 mins interval. I have extracted the unique id by regex extractor. The problem is, I can only pass the last unique id to "get" call instead of every unique id. Is there a way we can create dynamic regex-key and downstream the value for further use?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuZYt.png)

Answer (score 0):

There are certainly multiple ways in which you could solve for this.  To name a couple:

1. Capture each of the different POST response ID's as unique variables, which could then be used in future GET calls, each requesting with one of the unique ID's.
   Example: ID1, ID2, ID3, etc...
2. Create separate thread groups for each of these POST/GET scenarios.  The JMeter variable will only be local to the thread group, so they will be isolated from one another.  This would also provide the possibility of running them concurrently if so desired.
3. Using a variable (a count of sorts) to increment on each POST, and appending it to a common variable name. 
   Example: ID${count} . You would have to add a Beanshell Preprocessor to increment the count variable within each HTTP Request Sampler.

`int count = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("count"));
count = count + 1;
vars.put("count", count.toString());`

You could then iterate until reaching the value of count in a While Controller when making the GET requests, or you could decrement count. Both would serve the same function, provided the condition in the While statement is satisfied. Additionally you could use a Loop controller with count as the # of iterations, and simply have another count that increments for the life of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way will be using an incrementing postfix like:

1. Add [__counter()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__counter) function as a postfix for your "Reference Name" like

   [image: counter postfix]
2. Each time the Regular Expression Extractor will be called, a new `batchid_N` variable will be created where `N` is an incrementing number produced by the __counter() function

   [image: Variables originated from counter]
3. You will be able to access these variables values as `${batchid_1}`, `${batchid_2}`, etc. where required. There is also a possibility to use another JMeter Function or Variable as the postfix value via [__V()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) function like:

   - `${__V(batchid_${yourVar})}` - combine "batchid_" prefix with `${yourVar}` variable
   - `${__V(batchid_${__counter(,)})}` - combine "batchid_" prefix with __counter() function

See [How to Use JMeter Functions](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) article series for more information on above and others JMeter functions.